# Drawing a filled circle segment

Tags: graphics, vb6, drawing

I want to draw something like a pie chart segment filled with a certain color.

I know we can draw a circle using the `Me.Circle` function in a `PictureBox` to get a filled circle. However, when you add the start and end the circle becomes just a single lined arc.

Can anyone offer me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Check http://www.wiley.com/college/mckeown/0471418625/ppt/ch11.ppt

Comment: I realised the little bit of important information that was missed out in all tutorials (that your PPT had)... The segment parameters must be *NEGATIVE* for the circle to get connected. The whole day I been trying positive values. Thank you very very much qasimzee!